# How to dynamically attach behaviors to dynamically loaded elements in HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an HTML form being attached to a div element dynamically. How can I attach existing behavior to the newly added elements.

For example. I have methods like

```
$.fn.jqueryAjaxFormLoad - defined in jquery.ajaxload.js
$.fn.displayMessage  - defined in jquery.messagebar.js
```

already defined, which were loaded during page load. Now I want to append or make these available to the newly added form element and its children. What would be a best way to achieve this using jQuery.

The end expectation is that I can call

$('.form_element').displayMessage() on one of the form elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to run an event on click of an element:

```
$("#something").click(function(){
    alert("Something was clicked!");
});
```

Simply replace `click` with the event you want to use. You can see a list of the events at [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Events).

If your event isn't in the list of events at the above link, simply use this code:

```
$("#something").bind("touchstart",function(){
    alert("You tapped something!");
});
```

The above code will make an alert appear when the user taps the screen on a mobile device. 
Simply change touchstart with whatever event you need to use.

Ad@m

Comment: What is the behavior for plugins. I want to make the plugins available for newly added form elements.

Comment: @user210504 Some make you use `$("#something").bind()` and others use a callback function that is defined when they are initialized, for example `$("#something").pluginName({ someCallback:function(){ alert("Callback fired"); } });`. Ad@m

Answer (score 1):

You can bind handlers to dynamically added elements using jquery's [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's `.live()` you can bind event handlers onto objects and the events will be triggered even if new objects are added via AJAX.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

A simple example would be:

```
$('#foo').live('click', function() {
    // this will be called even if #foo is added minutes after the initial page load!
});
```

Comment: Better way is use .delegate().

Comment: how does it work for plugin. I just noticed that some of the methods which i want to call are plugins. How do I associate plugins to dynamically loaded elements.

for example: $.fn.displayMessage

Comment: That is a problem I ran into a couple days ago and in the case of my plugin it had a method to simply destroy all event handlers it had maintained so I would do that and then recreate the event handler. For example: $('.foo').draggable("destroy"); $('.foo').draggable(param_object); But I'm not sure if your plugin has anything similiar.